# Terminal - removing virus or rootlets

Tags: terminal, virus, rootkit

I found a file in my terminal named ~$E THINKERS.docx, I tried to removed it using the rm command but it keeps telling me no such file found. I think its a rootkit, since my antivirus doesn't detect it. Anyone can help me remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is lacking details...

I suppose you are working in Unix-like terminal and typing: `rm ~$E THINKERS.docx` and the expansion fail (look for "Tilde Expansion" in [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)).

Could you try: `rm '~$E THINKERS.docx'`?

If it were a rootkit, you most probably wouldn't see it...

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. It is a Mac (Unix-like) terminal. But the problem was solved. I needed to use the tilde. Thank you!